# How to generate a UCC/EAN 128 barcode with 128Code font?

Tags: flash, fonts, actionscript, gs1-128

I need to be able to generate UCC/EAN 128 barcodes with our ActionScript-based application. A already have the Code 128 font integrated, but need to create UCC/EAN 128 barcodes. Browsing information from Google, I found that the UCC/EAN 128 is actually a subversion of Code 128, so it hasn't got its own font. How can I generate UCC/EAN barcodes, then? I haven't found any answer browsing Google for hours :-(

I just know that UCC/EAN 128 has got some special prefix, but how to implement them inside the code correctly?

I need to use fonts.

Thanks in advance for some tips.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a code 39 and code 128 barcode generator using AS3. Feel free to use the code for your project.

http://bit.ly/OI9iHC